# Faster way to process 50 million records in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, etl, bulkinsert, insert-update

I'm trying to do a CDC on 60 million records in Oracle .
I need to check 60million source(TABLE_TEMP) records against the Target (TABLE) and do Insert , Update or soft Delete operations.
I tried to write individual queries and executed them but it takes really long time (more than 4 hrs) .

Here is what I already tried doing:

INSERT: (Check source records against target and if its a new record , insert into target)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (WID,A,B,C,DELETE_INDICATOR,DELETION_TIME,F,G,H) 
SELECT A,B,C,DELETE_INDICATOR,DELETION_TIME,F,G,H  FROM 
TABLE_TEMP   
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE  ON TABLE.A = TABLE_TEMP.A  AND TABLE.B = TABLE_TEMP.B AND TABLE.C = TABLE_TEMP.C  
WHERE TABLE.ID IS NULL
```

WID is the sequence

DELETE:(check source and target and if the target has any extra records than the source, then soft delete them. Soft delete because im using the same WID in my fact tables, so I don't really want to do hard delete)

```
UPDATE TABLE DELETE_INDICATOR = 'Y' ,
DELETION_TIME = TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE),
F = 'XXX' ,
F = 'YYY'  WHERE WID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
WID 
TABLE   
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TEMP
ON TABLE.A = TABLE_TEMP.A  AND TABLE.B = TABLE_TEMP.B AND TABLE.C = TABLE_TEMP.C   AND TABLE.DELETE_INDICATOR = 'N' 
WHERE TABLE_TEMP.A IS NULL AND TABLE_TEMP.B IS NULL  )
```

UPDATE: (check source and target and if there is any change in the data then update it- especially when a deleted record re-arrives in next run , I'm making it Active )

```
UPDATE TABLE SET DELETE_INDICATOR = 'N' ,
DELETION_TIME = TO_DATE(TO_DATE('29991231','YYYYMMDD')),
F = 'XXX' ,
G = 'YYY' 
WHERE WID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
WID 
FROM TABLE   
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TEMP  
ON TABLE.A = TABLE_TEMP.A  AND TABLE.B = TABLE_TEMP.B AND TABLE.C = TABLE_TEMP.C  AND DELETE_INDICATOR = 'Y' 
WHERE TABLE_TEMP.A IS NULL AND TABLE_TEMP.B IS NULL )
```

I also tried writing ORACLE MERGE but that also takes more than 4 hrs .

Can anyone please suggest the best approach to do this faster.

Comment: I would expect a single MERGE statement to run quicker than these individual statements but I don't believe there is an alternative solution that would be significantly faster - so all you can do is tune the statement(s) that you are running. Have you looked at the relevant EXPLAIN PLAN and have you got appropriate indexes on these tables?

Comment: Whether or not performance can be improved will also depend on what/where your current bottleneck is. Have you generated an AWR report to look at overall system performance?

Comment: Make sure you manually gather statistics on TEMP_TABLE right after it is loaded - run something like `begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA NAME', 'TEMP_TABLE'); end;` whenever there is a large (percentage) change in that table. I would guess that step is missing, so Oracle has old statistics that think the TEMP_TABLE is much smaller, and therefore the SQL uses a NESTED LOOPS operation (good for joining small amounts of data) instead of a HASH JOIN operation (good for joining large amounts of data). Use `explain plan for insert...` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)` to verify.